# Como validar la primera <option> de un <select> mediante evento 'change'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo un `<select>` con varias `<option>` que toman diferentes valores a medida que el usuario va eligiendo una distinta. El problema es que la primera option nunca tomará su valor salvo que el usuario active el evento 'change', osea, que primero elija otra opción de la lista y luego vuelva a elegir la primera opción.

**JQuery:**

```
$('#categorias').on('change', () => {
    var value = $('#categorias').val();
    if(value === "Dulces de Leche") {
        $('#idCategoria').val(1);
    }
    else if(value === "Cremas") {
        $('#idCategoria').val(2);
    }
    else if(value === "Chocolates") {
        $('#idCategoria').val(3);
    }
    if(value === "Frutales") {
        $('#idCategoria').val(4);
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col s12 l8">
                <!-- TODO: Hacer una clase aparte para hacer esto dinámico -->
                <input id="idCategoria" th:value="0" th:field="*{idCategoria}" hidden="hidden"/>
                <select id="categorias" th:field="*{categoria}">
                    <option value="" disabled="disabled">Categoria</option>
                    <option value="Dulces de Leche">Dulce de Leche</option>
                    <option value="Cremas">Cremas</option>
                    <option value="Chocolates">Chocolates</option>
                    <option value="Frutales">Frutales</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

¿Que evento puedo utilizar acá para tener la misma funcionalidad pero que la primera opción también tome su valor en caso de que el usuario haga el submit directamente, sin antes haber elegido otra opción?

Comment: La primera opcion, es la de por defecto. Cuando se incialice la pagina, llama tú manualmente al codigo encargado de poner valor a la Categoria  para que empiece con ese valor. luego, si cambia de opcion, ya tienes el `onchange`

Comment: nao comprendo :/  LLama manualmente al código ? :/

Comment: El codigo que tienes dentro del evento onchange, lo sacas de la funcion anonima y lo metes en una funcion aparte. dentro del onchange llamas a esa funcion que has creado, ej `cambiarCategoria()` o como sea. Y lo que digo es que al inicializar la pagina, que llames a esa funcion para que lo haga por defecto para el option 1.

Comment: @NachoZveDeLaTorre cuando dices la primera opcion te refieres a `<option value="" disabled="disabled">Categoria</option>` ?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav, no, me refiero a la opción "Dulces de Leche", perdón por no aclarar ! Osea, si el user elige directamente esa opción y hace el submit, el evento 'change' logicamente no se activará!

Comment: OK quieres que si el elige dulce de leche haga directamente el submit pero si elige otra opcion haga el evento change no?

Comment: @NachoZveDeLaTorre otra pregunta, si elige dulce de leche no debe de hacer que? osea solo veo que asignas el valor a un campo oculto, si eliges dulce de leche no debe de asignar ese valor? te pregunto porque dices que si elige esa opción el evento change no se activara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No existe ningún evento que te sirva para esto, podrías efectuar al cargar la pagina el seteo del valor de idCategoria a 1 directamente o controlar habilitar el botón de enviar (submit) cuando se hayan escogido las opciones, obligando al usuario a elegir si o si una. Ejemplo como se haría:

```js
$('#categorias').on('change', () => {
    var value = $('#categorias').val();
    
    if(value) {
       $('.warning').hide();
       $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    
    switch(value) {
      case "Dulces de Leche":
        $('#idCategoria').val(1);
        break;
      case "Cremas":
        $('#idCategoria').val(2);
        break;
      case "Chocolates":
        $('#idCategoria').val(3);
        break;
      case "Frutales":
        $('#idCategoria').val(4);
        break;
    }
    
    
});
$('#form').on('submit', (e) => {
  if(!$('#idCategoria').val()) {
    $('.warning').show();
    console.log('You have to select a category');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.warning {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
<div class="col s12 l8">
                <!-- TODO: Hacer una clase aparte para hacer esto dinámico -->
                <input id="idCategoria" th:value="0" th:field="*{idCategoria}" />
                <select id="categorias" th:field="*{categoria}">
                    <option value="" selected  disabled="disabled">Seleccione una categoria</option>
                    <option value="Dulces de Leche">Dulce de Leche</option>
                    <option value="Cremas">Cremas</option>
                    <option value="Chocolates">Chocolates</option>
                    <option value="Frutales">Frutales</option>
                </select>
                <label class="warning">*</label>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" disabled/>
            </form>
```

Comment: Gracias <3 !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer que el valor se establezca en el submit del form, algo así:

```
$('form').on('submit', () => {
    var value = $('#categorias').val();
    switch (value) {
        case "":
            $('#idCategoria').val(0);
            break;
        case "Dulces de Leche":
            $('#idCategoria').val(1);
            break;
        case "Cremas":
            $('#idCategoria').val(2);
            break;
        case "Chocolates":
            $('#idCategoria').val(3);
            break;
        case "Frutales":
            $('#idCategoria').val(4);
            break;
    }
});
```

Otra posibilidad sería que el elemento "idCategoria" ya tenga el valor 0 por defecto.

¡Suerte!